# Get specific string value from my response data

Tags: java

I am getting response data from my java code, I hit URL as follows,

```
    String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=mkyong";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

I am getting the html data as string values...

I want to get a hidden value from this response data.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="HREF.DUMMY.MENSYS.1"
        value="-X-tB--3TF8LlA02j-LKYRAT75rwYwwchuvSyZ9vWVwQ0"
        id="url" />
```

How to get this value?

Comment: what kind of hidden value?

Comment: Updated with that, pls take a look now.

Comment: use `Jsoup` for that [check this](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Jsoup-Example)

Comment: Jsoup is used to read the url, right? I want to go for response data. Is it possible in Jsoup.

Comment: no it is not used to read url,it is used to extract tag from `HTML` document..check source of link i posted

Comment: By this way, I need to save html file and then need to read that file. Is there a way to get string value from response after it deliverd?

Comment: no you dont have to save anything just pass to html link to `Document` object and get element from there

Comment: Can you pls gimme a solution as answer, I am just confused.. As of now my response data in String format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94304/discussion-between-ratwanska-and-mohit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can,

Just use the following code with your response,

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(response.toString());
    Element el= doc.select("type[hidden]");
    Streing val = el.getAttr("value");
```

Then you can find your element from the doc object.